# sqlite3 differences on raspbian and manjaro?

Tags: python, sqlite

I wrote a script on my laptop, which is running Manjaro, that populates a database with values from a CSV file. It runs fine on my laptop, but when I ran the script on my Raspberry Pi 3 (running raspbian stretch) it would not run, giving me an error at the following line:

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT simplified FROM dictionary WHERE (traditional = ? OR simplified = ?)''', (char, char))

sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use
a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). 
It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

The two `char` variables above are Chinese characters. Why does it work on one system but not the other?

Does it have something to do with the package versions? On Manjaro, I have sqlite3 version 3.20.1, and Raspbian is running 3.16.2 (though I tried uninstalling the sqlite3 package on Raspbian and running the script, and it seemed to make no difference, it still attempted to run, so maybe the sqlite3 library is a part of the main library?)

How should I go about fixing this? I already have the utf-8 encoding specified at the top of the file

**Edit:**

here is more code. the cursor being passed in is an sqlite3.Cursor object

```
def convertToSimplified(sentence, cursor):
    s = ""
    sentence = sentence.replace('\n', '')
    for char in sentence:
        cursor.execute('''SELECT simplified FROM dictionary WHERE (traditional = ? OR simplified = ?)''', (char, char))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is not None:
            s += result[0]
        else:
            s += char

    print(s)
    return s
```

Comment: `python --version`

Comment: It looks like the script is not run by the same python version on your two OSes.